# How to modify a pandas DataFrame in a function so that changes are seen by the caller?

Tags: python, pandas

I find myself doing repetitive tasks to various `[pandas][1]` DataFrames, so I made a function to do the processing. How do I modify `df` in the function `process_df(df)` so that the caller sees all changes (without assigning a return value)?

A simplified version of the code:

```
def process_df(df):
    df.columns = map(str.lower, df.columns)

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1], 'B': [2]})
process_df(df)
print df
```

> ```
>    A  B 
> 0  1  2
> ```

EDIT new code:

```
def process_df(df):
    df = df.loc[:, 'A']

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1], 'B': [2]})
process_df(df)
print df
```

> ```
>    A  B 
> 0  1  2
> ```

Comment: IIUC your code is working, after function `process_df` column names becomes `[a, b]`

Comment: Indeed it is. My bad. In the process of simplifying I left out the part that does not work. I will repost as a new question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indexing a `DataFrame` using `ix`, `loc`, `iloc`, etc. returns a view of the underlying data (it is a read operation). In order to modify the contents of the frame you will need to use in-place transforms. For example,

```
def process_df(df):
    # drop all columns except for A
    df.drop(df.columns[df.columns != 'A'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df = DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[1,2,3]})
process_df(df)
```

To change the order of columns, you can do something like this:

```
def process_df(df):
    # swap A and B
    df.columns = ['B', 'A']
    df[['B', 'A']] = df[['A', 'B']]
```

Comment: How would I go about re-arranging the order of multiple columns? All the examples I have seen to do this begin with `df = ` ... which wouldn't be an in-place transform.

Comment: Added an example above. It's not pretty. Out of curiosity, why the restriction that you can't use the return value of `process_df`?

Comment: Code (and error) reduction. The function is always used to modify the existing DataFrame.