# Confusion about modifying DataFrame within Function

Tags: python, function, pandas

when working within a function, I am struggling with understanding why sometimes I can modify dataframe values and other times I cannot. For example, variable assignment works without a return statement, but pd.get_dummies seems to need me to use return statement at end of the function.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'x' : np.linspace(0,10,3) ,
    'y' : np.linspace(10,20,3) ,
    'cat1'  : ['dog','cat','fish'] , 
    'cat2' : ['website1','website1','website2'] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


    cat1    cat2    x   y
0   dog  website1   0.0 10.0
1   cat  website1   5.0 15.0
2   fish website2   10.020.0
```

#### Modifies the original dataframe

```
def change_variable(df): 
        df['x']  = 999
```

#### Doesn't Modify

```
def ready_for_ml(df):
    pd.get_dummies(df,columns=['cat1','cat2'])
```

#### My work-around:

```
def ready_for_ml_return_df_version(df):
    df = pd.get_dummies(df,columns=['cat1','cat2'])
    return df

df = ready_for_ml_return_df_version(df)
     x   y     cat  dog fish website1 website2
0   0.0 10.0    0   1    0     1         0
1   5.0 15.0    1   0    0     1         0
2   10.020.0    0   0    1     0         1
```

I have read about using inplace transforms as a solution. [How to modify a pandas DataFrame in a function so that changes are seen by the caller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35145472/how-to-modify-a-pandas-dataframe-in-a-function-so-that-changes-are-seen-by-the-c) but, I pd.get_dummies doesn't seem to have an inplace argument. So, I am curious about this function but, also more broadly the underlying behavior.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: pd.get_dummies returns a new dataframe.  Many times people want the original dataframe and the manipulated dataframe.  Your solutions seems fine to me.

Comment: thx Geoff. Just checking my understanding here, anytime a new DataFrame created within a function it is a local copy. So, when you return the DataFrame at the end you need to assign to new global variable?

Comment: Yes, anything (variables, lists, DataFrames, etc.) created within a function are local to the function unless specifically declared global.  Return is how a function sends data back out.  

In your example df = ready_for_ml_return_df_version(df) is overwriting the global variable df with the returned DataFrame.  But you could have easily done, df2 = ready_for_ml_return_df_version(df).  Where df2 is the new DataFrame and you still have a copy of your original DataFrame, df.